# C returning answer through parameters ( refernce)

Tags: function, pointers, parameters, reference, ansi-c

Hy everyone,

pls consider this small code, and help me to figure out, why it's not working?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void setup(int* helo) {
    helo = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    (*helo) = 8;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int* helo = NULL;
    setup(helo);
    printf("Value: %s \n", (*helo));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the problme is, that when I'm trying to read "helo" it is still NULL

Comment: Aren't you basically passing "null" into setup?  Once in setup, you allocate new memory for your int - but how is that address communicated back with the caller?

Comment: it should do it automatically...

Comment: How?  helo is a null pointer, it's pointing nowhere.  You pass that null pointer into setup, and you then change the address of that pointer to a newly allocated piece of memory.  You set that piece of memory to 8.  The int* back in main is still pointing to null..  What you want is to pass a pointer to a pointer, then initialize /that/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for one of **two options** here. You can either **take the memory pointer allocation out** of the equation, and pass the memory address of a standard variable:

```
void setup(int* helo) 
{
    *helo = 8;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int helo = 0;
    setup(helo);
    printf("Value: %d\n", helo);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you want to stick with your approach, **the signature of your function needs to change** to receive a pointer to a pointer:

```
void setup(int** helo) {
    *helo = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(*helo) = 8;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int* helo = NULL;
    setup(&helo);
    printf("Value: %d \n", (*helo));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The reason for this is that `setup(int* helo)` **receives a copy** of `int* helo` declared in `main()`, and this local copy will point to the same place. So whatever you do with `helo` inside `setup()` will be changing the **local copy** of the variable and not `helo` from `main()`. That's why you need to change the signature to `setup(int** helo)`.

Answer (score 0):

can you try `printf("Value: %d \n", (*helo));` instead of `printf("Value: %s \n", (*helo));`?

Comment: Its the same, I get NULL value, I don't know why, but in the function "malloc" works correctly but it's not returning the value...

Answer (score 0):

c is **pass by value**. When you pass a parameter to a function, a copy of it is made. You need to receive as pointer to pointer to achieve C++ feature of pass by reference.

```
void setup(int** helo) {
    *helo = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    (*(*helo)) = 8;
}
```

And at the call it as -

```
setup(&helo) ;
```