# c function and multiple value returning

Tags: c

My question is in general how to use pointers in functions correctly.

if to be more specific I need to write a function the recives 3 values from a user and then retruns it to the main one for further actions.
This is the code I have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int inputThree(int, int, int);

int sortTwo(int, int);

int sortThree(int, int);

int main()

{

    int a=0, b=0, c=0;
    printf("before: func %d \n", b);
    inputThree(a,b,c);
    printf("after func: %d%d%d \n",a,b,c);
    getch();

}

int inputThree(int a, int b, int c)

{

    printf("Input three integers values: \n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    return 0;

}
```

I'm intersted in understanding how to keep the values of scanf via pointers. When I return to the main function they are lost because they aren't global...

Also, I couldn't leave the function inputthree without parameters even though I want it to get them from `scanf` itself, so I had to put some values for it to run.

thanks in advance!

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570, *6.5.2.2 Function calls 4 An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. In preparing for the call
to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument. 93)A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the arguments. On the other hand, it is possible to pass a pointer to an object, and the function may change the value of the object pointed to.* C is call-by-value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C returning answer through parameters ( refernce)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917840/c-returning-answer-through-parameters-refernce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass pointers to the variables from `main` to `inputThree`.

Change the function declaration.

```
int inputThree(int* aPtr, int* bPtr, int* cPtr);
```

Change the call.

```
inputThree(&a, &b, &c);
```

Change the implementation.

```
int inputThree(int* aPtr, int* bPtr, int* cPtr)
{
    printf("Input three integers values: \n");
    scanf("%d%d%d", aPtr, bPtr, cPtr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either return a struct or make a function that handles passed pointers as argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo{
    int x;
    int y;
};

//one way
struct Foo do_work();

//or another
void do_work(int *x, int *y);


int main(void) {

    return 0;
}

struct Foo do_work(){
//e.g.
    struct Foo foo;
    foo.x = 1;
    foo.y = 2;
    return foo;
}

void do_work1(int *x, int *y){
//e.g
    *x = 1;
    *y = 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Technically, only 1 thing (or none) can be returned from a function at a time. If you wanted to change the values of two or more variables via a function even after the function ends, you would need to pass into the function's parameters/arguments the memory reference of the variable.

Comment: You could return a `struct` containing any number of values.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to do this. Passing by pointer is not the only way. A struct would also be a very possible option.

Comment: Ty for the answers will try to implament them!